# How to properly define a move constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

I did search the internet and found 3 ways of defining a move constructor:

1. Relying on compiler:

   ```
   T(T&& other) = default;
   ```
2. Dereference `this` pointer:

   ```
   T(T&& other) {
     *this = std::move(other);
   }
   ```
3. Explicitly reassign all members:

   ```
   T(T&& other) {
     T.a = other.a;
     T.b = other.b;
     //...
   }
   ```

Which one is the proper way ? (And is the second one even correct?)

Comment: The second isn't correct (you can't generally refer to an object that doesn't exist), the the third one is silly.

Comment: @KerrekSB I found the second one from MSDN website: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293665.aspx maybe MSVC support it.. not sure about GCC

Comment: I found the third one from that page too...

Comment: The third one looks like a bad copy constructor (no use of constructor initialization list).

Comment: @texasbruce: That's a shame, but it's just outrageously silly. If anything, you should define the assignment operator in terms of the move constructor!

Comment: The second one is funny, indeed. It simply employs move assignment operator. You will still have to provide it.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Why second isn't correct? What is the difference between `this->moveinit(std::move(other))` and `this->operator=(std::move(other))`? the latter is same as `*this=std::move(other)`.

Comment: @Nawaz: `*this` is a dangerous thing, because it insinuates that the object exists. But we're still *in the constructor*, so the object doesn't actually exist yet.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Sorry I don't understand the problem. `=` is just a function just like `init()` or something. Do you imply `this->init()` is bad?

Comment: @Nawaz: Yes. Calling *any* member function in a constructor is hairy, because you need additional guarantees that the member functions don't expect a state that may not have yet been constructed. It's not outright impossible, but it's a lot more mental overhead and non-locality.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The proper generic way is to move-construct each member, but that's what the defauted version does anyway:

```
T(T && rhs)
: a(std::move(rhs.a))
, b(std::move(rhs.b))
{  }
```

As a rough rule, you should use the default definition if this is all you need, and you should write an ex­pli­cit move constructor if you're doing something that ex­pli­citly *implements* move semantics, such as a unique-ownership resource manager:

```
URM(URM && rhs)
: resource(rhs.resource)
{
    rhs.resource = nullptr;
}
```

The indicator for whether this is appropriate is probably whether your class has a user-defined de­struc­tor. In the example, the destructor would release the managed resource, and this must happen only once, so the moved-from object must be modified.

---

This is unrelated, but since you are mentioning the assignment operator, here's the popular swap-and-assign/swap idiom:

```
void swap(URM & rhs) noexcept      // assume members are noexcept-swappable!
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(resource, rhs.resource);
    // ...
}

URM & operator=(URM rhs) noexcept  // pass by value
{
    rhs.swap(*this);
    return *this;
}
```

The beauty of this approach is that you only need one single version of the assignment operator that works for temporaries and non-temporaries alike, using move construction when appropriate, and as long as all your members are well-designed, you also only need one single `swap` function. On top of that, if the swap function doesn't throw (which a well-designed class should allow), then your assignment operator doesn't throw, since all the possible exceptions would already occur at the call site.

Comment: Is the last really needed if, for example, `resource` is a `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: No. The example might be an *implementation* of `unique_ptr`.

Comment: How about the default one? Can I safely use it at all?

Comment: @texasbruce: You can and should use the defaulted move constructor if all your class members are sane, and individually movable. In a well designed class this is going to be the case, and in fact, *if* you ever need to define a move constructor manually, then that class should essentially not be doing anything else (other than managing one resource, that is).

Answer (score 1):

```
T(T&& other)
: data(0) // initialize members
{
    swap(other); // where the class has a member function swap or std::swap(this->data, other.data)
}
```